# List comprehension for first 10 alphabets

Tags: python, list

I am trying to generate a list comprehension for first 10 letters.

```
letters = [l for l in 'a-j']
print(letters)
```

Output:

```
['a', '-', 'h']
```

This doesn't produce the expected output.How do I generate a list of first 10 alphabets?

Comment: `a-j` looks like a regex thing. Are you unhappy with `letters = [l for l in 'abcdefghij']`?

Comment: If you don't want a character range class, you could always hard-code it with `letters = list('abcdefghij')`.

Answer (score 8):

Use `string.ascii_lowercase` which contains the lowercase alphabets stored by default.

```
>>> import string
>>> string.ascii_lowercase
'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
>>> list(string.ascii_lowercase[:10])
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j']
```

Comment: Because OP is trying to figure  out how to get the chars between `a` and `j`, maybe `list(string.ascii_lowercase[string.ascii_lowercase.index('a'):string.ascii_l
owercase.index('f')+1])` would be more clear?